# How do I tell where Google Fit is getting step data?

Tags: google-fit

I have activity tracking disabled in Google Fit. I have three apps (HabitBull, MyFitnessPal, and Progression) connected to it and I don't believe they've recorded any step data. Google Fit shows 31 miscellaneous steps from yesterday and 639 from today. There isn't an indicator in the app showing where it came from, for example my weight is recorded in Google Fit and shows it came from MyFitnessPal.

Comment: There is no google-fit tag here on SuperUser. Edit: perhaps this should be migrated to Android Stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the steps shown come from activities. The only time I see Fit record steps (configured like yours) is from a specific activity. Check the 'activity' card/area and try to determine which app sent the data from there.